# Почему не сработало событие click?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Блок создается динамически на странице:

```
<div class="settings"></div>
```

Событие клика:

```
$(document).on("click", ".settings", function(e) {
        $(this).addClass('open');
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А если `$(this).addClass('open');` заменить на `alert(1)`, покажет алерт?

Comment: Нет, не показывает.

Comment: Какая версия jquery?

Comment: jQuery v1.11.1

Comment: А в консоли никаких не выводится ошибок?

Comment: Совершенно никаких.

Comment: Тогда должно все работать -> [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/oLny4cr4/1/).